# In React-Table, how to check/uncheck all checkboxes in a row or column

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox, react-table

I have a table using `react-table` with checkboxes in rows.
I also added a "check all" checkbox in the 1st cell of a row, to **check/uncheck** all the checkboxes in every column of that row.

The problem is when I implemented the "check all" checkbox, it worked as intended but when I **check/uncheck** a checkbox individually it doesn't **check/uncheck**.

#### Table Component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import setTableColumns from '../utils/setTableColumns';

const RolePermissionsTable = () => {
  return (
    <ReactTable
      defaultPageSize={10}
      data={capacity.roles}
      columns={setTableColumns()}
      showPagination={false}
      getTrProps={(state, rowData, column, instance) => {
        return {
          onClick(event) {
            const row = event.currentTarget;
            const targetEntity = row.querySelector(
              '.RoleTarget [type="checkbox"]'
            );
            const allCheckboxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(
              row.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]')
            );
            const permissionsCheckboxes = allCheckboxes.slice(
              1,
              allCheckboxes.length
            );
            const isChecked = targetEntity.checked;

            permissionsCheckboxes.map(permissionsCheckbox => {
              permissionsCheckbox.checked = isChecked ? isChecked : null;
            });
          },
        };
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

#### Column Headers

```
import React from 'react';

// imported above for the table
const setTableColumns = () => {
  return [
    {
      Header: 'Entities',
      accessor: 'target',
      Cell: rowData => (
        <span className="RoleTarget" key={rowData.original.target}>
          <input
            id={`CheckAll-${rowData.original.target}`}
            type="checkbox"
          />
          <span className="RoleTarget__name">{rowData.original.target}</span>
        </span>
      ),
    },
    {
      Header: 'Add',
      accessor: 'add',
      Cell: rowData => {
        return (
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            defaultChecked={rowData.original.permissions.add}
            id={`${rowData.original.target}-${rowData.original.userId}`}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      Header: 'Modify',
      accessor: 'modify',
      Cell: rowData => {
        return (
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            defaultChecked={rowData.original.permissions.modify}
            id={`${rowData.original.target}-${rowData.original.userId}`}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      Header: 'Delete',
      accessor: 'delete',
      Cell: rowData => {
        return (
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            defaultChecked={rowData.original.permissions.delete}
          />
        );
      },
    },
  ];
};
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly or is there a better way for this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to say if there is "a better way", if your solution solves your problem it's already good. I do think there is a simpler way.
There is a simple package that solves this problem [grouped-checkboxes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@createnl/grouped-checkboxes).

[View on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-mountain-g7edm)

In your case it will look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable, { ReactTableDefaults } from 'react-table';
import setTableColumns from '../utils/setTableColumns';
import { CheckboxGroup } from '@createnl/grouped-checkboxes';

const TrComponent = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
 <tr {...rest}>
   <CheckboxGroup>{children}</CheckboxGroup>
 </tr>
);

const RolePermissionsTable = () => {
  Object.assign(ReactTableDefaults, {
    TrComponent: TrComponent
  });

  return (
    <ReactTable
      defaultPageSize={10}
      data={capacity.roles}
      columns={setTableColumns()}
      showPagination={false}
    />
  );
```

Column Headers

```
import React from 'react';
import { AllCheckerCheckbox, Checkbox } from '@createnl/grouped-checkboxes';

// imported above for the table
const setTableColumns = () => {
  return [
    {
      Header: 'Entities',
      accessor: 'target',
      Cell: rowData => (
        <span className="RoleTarget" key={rowData.original.target}>
          <AllCheckerCheckbox
            id={`CheckAll-${rowData.original.target}`}
          />
          <span className="RoleTarget__name">{rowData.original.target}</span>
        </span>
      ),
    },
    {
      Header: 'Add',
      accessor: 'add',
      Cell: rowData => {
        return (
          <Checkbox
            checked={rowData.original.permissions.add}
            id={`${rowData.original.target}-${rowData.original.userId}`}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      Header: 'Modify',
      accessor: 'modify',
      Cell: rowData => {
        return (
          <Checkbox
            checked={rowData.original.permissions.modify}
            id={`${rowData.original.target}-${rowData.original.userId}`}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      Header: 'Delete',
      accessor: 'delete',
      Cell: rowData => {
        return (
          <Checkbox
            checked={rowData.original.permissions.delete}
          />
        );
      },
    },
  ];
};
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your solution works but it checks every single checkbox on the table. What I want is, it should only check/uncheck all the checkboxes on the same row as the checkAll checkbox. How do I do that with the `grouped-checkboxes` module?

Comment: Hi SeyAde, i've updated the code and added a codesandbox for you to play around with. I override the defualt tr component and add a checkboxgroup to it. Also dont forget to change defaultChecked to checked. 
More about overriding components: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#component-overrides

Comment: It's working now. Thanks Alexej for your help! Is this a react module you're working on to release publicly?